# Can i uses Google Places API with string input

Tags: android, google-maps

I am making a restaurant app which will provide the directions to a certain restaurant. I have a database of restaurants but this has the location of the restaurants in terms of a string. I read how Google maps can be used to get directions for the app, but it says using longitude and latitude. In my apps case, user selects an area from a drop-down and i want to show all the restaurants in that selected location on a map. Not able t figure out how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called Geocoding. It will transform a location name into coordinates and vice versa. For POIs you can use the [Google Places Search API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search), because the Google Geocoder APIs are designed for street addresses.